Pytorch distributed learning error when running unit test
I am writing a part of a project, which focuses on partitioning a dataset and distribute each chunk, together with a global machine learning model to each worker node in a distributed training environment. I am using Pytorch for this. I am having this error when I ran the unit test, but I have not been able to figure out why. Can anyone help me?
data_partitioning.py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, random_split
from torch.nn import Module
import torch.distributed as dist
import io

def partition_dataset(dataset: Dataset, num_workers: int) -> list[Dataset]:
    """
    Parameters:
    - dataset: The dataset to be partitioned.
    - num_workers: The number of partitions to create, typically the number of workers.

    Returns:
    - List of datasets, one for each worker.
    """
    if len(dataset) == 0:
        raise ValueError("The dataset is empty")
    if num_workers <= 0:
        raise ValueError("Invalid number of workers")
    partition_size = len(dataset) // num_workers
    partitions = [partition_size] * num_workers
    remainder = len(dataset) - partition_size * num_workers
    if remainder > 0:
        partitions[-1] += remainder

    return random_split(dataset, partitions)

def master_node_distribute(backend: str, init_method: str, model: Module, dataset: Dataset, world_size: int):
    """
    Master node function to distribute the model and dataset partitions to worker nodes.

    Parameters:
    - backend and init_method: Parameters for init_process_group
    - model: The global model to be trained.
    - dataset: The full dataset to be partitioned.
    - world_size: The total number of workers.
    """
    dist.init_process_group(backend=backend, init_method=init_method, rank=0, world_size=world_size)
    # partition data
    partitions = partition_dataset(dataset, world_size)

    # serialize model
    buffer = io.BytesIO()
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), buffer)
    buffer.seek(0)
    model_tensor = torch.tensor(bytearray(buffer.read()), dtype=torch.uint8)

    for rank in range(1, world_size):
        # send data
        data_tensor = torch.tensor(partitions[rank], dtype=torch.float32)
        dist.send(tensor=data_tensor, dst=rank)

        # send model
        dist.send(tensor=model_tensor, dst=rank)

data_partitioning_unit_test.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock, call
import torch
from data_partitioning import master_node_distribute
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from torch.nn import Module
import torch

class MockDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.data = list(range(size))

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.data[idx]

class MockModel(Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MockModel, self).__init__()
        self.layer = torch.nn.Linear(10, 1)

class TestDataPartitioning(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('data_partitioning.random_split')
    @patch('data_partitioning.dist')
    @patch('data_partitioning.io.BytesIO')
    @patch('data_partitioning.torch')
    @patch('torch.distributed.init_process_group')
    def test_master_node_distribute(self, mock_init_process_group, mock_torch, mock_bytes_io, mock_dist, mock_random_split):
        mock_init_process_group.return_value = None
        model = MockModel()
        dataset = MockDataset(100)
        world_size = 4
        backend='gloo'
        init_method=""
        # Mock partitions
        partitions = [MockDataset(25) for _ in range(world_size)]

        # Mock buffer
        buffer = Mock()
        mock_bytes_io.return_value = buffer
        model_state = Mock()
        mock_torch.save.return_value = model_state
        buffer.read.return_value = b'model_state_data'

        with patch('data_partitioning.random_split', return_value=partitions):
            master_node_distribute(backend, init_method, model, dataset, world_size)

        # Check that data and model were sent to each worker
        expected_data_calls = [
            call(torch.tensor(partitions[i], dtype=torch.float32), dst=i)
            for i in range(1, world_size)
        ]
        expected_model_call = [
                            call(torch.tensor(bytearray(buffer.read()), dtype=torch.uint8), dst=i)
                            for i in range(1, world_size)
                            ]
        expected_calls = expected_data_calls + expected_model_call * (world_size - 1)
        mock_dist.send.assert_has_calls(expected_calls, any_order=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()

Error when running:
    raise AssertionError(
AssertionError: 'send' does not contain all of (call(tensor([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13.,
        14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24.]), dst=1), call(tensor([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13.,
        14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24.]), dst=2), call(tensor([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9., 10., 11., 12., 13.,
        14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20., 21., 22., 23., 24.]), dst=3), call(tensor([109, 111, 100, 101, 108,  95, 115, 116,  97, 116, 101,  95, 100,  97,
        116,  97], dtype=torch.uint8), dst=1), call(tensor([109, 111, 100, 101, 108,  95, 115, 116,  97, 116, 101,  95, 100,  97,
        116,  97], dtype=torch.uint8), dst=2), call(tensor([109, 111, 100, 101, 108,  95, 115, 116,  97, 116, 101,  95, 100,  97,
        116,  97], dtype=torch.uint8), dst=3), call(tensor([109, 111, 100, 101, 108,  95, 115, 116,  97, 116, 101,  95, 100,  97,
        116,  97], dtype=torch.uint8), dst=1), call(tensor([109, 111, 100, 101, 108,  95, 115, 116,  97, 116, 101,  95, 100,  97,
        116,  97], dtype=torch.uint8), dst=2), call(tensor([109, 111, 100, 101, 108,  95, 115, 116,  97, 116, 101,  95, 100,  97,
        116,  97], dtype=torch.uint8), dst=3), call(tensor([109, 111, 100, 101, 108,  95, 115, 116,  97, 116, 101,  95, 100,  97,
        116,  97], dtype=torch.uint8), dst=1), call(tensor([109, 111, 100, 101, 108,  95, 115, 116,  97, 116, 101,  95, 100,  97,
        116,  97], dtype=torch.uint8), dst=2), call(tensor([109, 111, 100, 101, 108,  95, 115, 116,  97, 116, 101,  95, 100,  97,
        116,  97], dtype=torch.uint8), dst=3)) in its call list, found [call(tensor=<MagicMock name='torch.tensor()' id='4696420848'>, dst=1), call(tensor=<MagicMock name='torch.tensor()' id='4696420848'>, dst=1), call(tensor=<MagicMock name='torch.tensor()' id='4696420848'>, dst=2), call(tensor=<MagicMock name='torch.tensor()' id='4696420848'>, dst=2), call(tensor=<MagicMock name='torch.tensor()' id='4696420848'>, dst=3), call(tensor=<MagicMock name='torch.tensor()' id='4696420848'>, dst=3)] instead

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.006s

